# Как лучше хранить временные данные в Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Я создаю систему управления на yii2. У меня есть задача создать компанию и сразу же в этой форме сделать добавление офисов, которых может быть много.

Офисы привязываются к компании через поле `company_id`.

Сейчас сделал просто добавление группы полей для создания офиса, но такое решение не нравится. Хотелось бы сделать кнопку "Добавить офис" и при нажатии открывать модальное окно, заполнять и сохранять. Но как тогда делать привязку? Компании еще нету.

Пока у меня 2 варианта:

1. при заходе на форму генерировать некий ключ, который записывать офисам и при сохранение компании искать офисы с этим ключом и присваивать id компании;
2. хранить в сессии данные про офисы.

Оба варианта пугают тем, что если не сохранить компанию - будет мусор. Как это можно обойти? Или может есть более правильное решение?

P.S. Возможно ли открыть транзакцию и потом в нужный момент закрыть ее?

Comment: Я что-то не понял. Вот вы вводите данные компании, но не сохраняете. Потом добавляете офис, но сохраняете его сразу ??? Что за бред

Comment: посмотрите в сторону UUID

Comment: @AlexKhonko вы имеете ввиду все таки использовать первый вариант?

Comment: @Diefair да, примерно так. Вы можете сделать ход конём, и вместо классического числового ID сделать ID именно как UUID.Это поможет вам при записи

Comment: дык просто разрешите (если нельзя) иметь в базе офисы без привязки к компании, а при сохранении из модалки запишите их id-шники в форму компании по событию или как удобно

Comment: @Blacknife когда работает 2 человека, как понять при сохранение где кого офисы?

Comment: а какая принципиальная разница сколько человек работает если у вас в форме компании будут id`s всех офисов сохраненных через модальное окно здесь же? если надо понимать где-кого офисы, наверное их тоже к юзерам лучше привязывать а не только к компании, тогда в любое время создания компании можете юзеру пальцем показать что есть офисы без привязки и т.д. и т.п., вариантов куча, не зная бизнес-логики вообще сложно что-то тут советовать

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо заполнять полную форму, не сохраняя никакие данные, а уже после заполнения сохранить всё за один раз: одновременно и компанию, и её офисы

Comment: суть задачи - что офисов может быть несколько. пока что сделал привязку по UUID